# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/crash/crash-2016-09-04-15-35-25-1472974525277.log: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: android

The following code is what I wrote for saving crash message in a local file

```
        try {
            long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
            String time = formatter.format(new Date());
            String fileName = "crash-" + time + "-" + timestamp + ".log";
            if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                String path = Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .getAbsolutePath()
                        + "/crash/";
                File dir = new File(path);
                if (!dir.exists()) {
                    dir.mkdirs();
                }
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path + fileName);
                fos.write(sb.toString().getBytes());
                fos.close();
            }
            return fileName;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "an error occured while writing file...", e);
        }
```

But When my app crashed.The log show me some errors.It's shown as follows:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/crash/crash-2016-09-04-15-35-25-1472974525277.log: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:459)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:127)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:116)
at com.attendance.exception.CrashHandler.saveCrashInfo2File(CrashHandler.java:212)
at com.attendance.exception.CrashHandler.handleException(CrashHandler.java:135)
at com.attendance.exception.CrashHandler.uncaughtException(CrashHandler.java:88)
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:445)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87) 
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:127) 
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:116) 
at com.attendance.exception.CrashHandler.saveCrashInfo2File(CrashHandler.java:212) 
at com.attendance.exception.CrashHandler.handleException(CrashHandler.java:135) 
at com.attendance.exception.CrashHandler.uncaughtException(CrashHandler.java:88) 
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693) 
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

I have add permissions in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

What is the problem?Thanks for you help!

Comment: did you grant permission to write into external storage? you need to do it programatically.

Comment: @AngelKoh Yes,I did.

Answer (score 2):

This is the answer i gave for the same issue in another question.

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.

you need to manually code the permission granting part (besides defining it in the manifest).

the following is a snippet from developer.android.com

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

// Should we show an explanation?
if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

    // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
    // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
    // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

} else {

    // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is an
    // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
    // result of the request.
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your gradel like :

```js
targetSdkVersion 22
```

instead of

```js
targetSdkVersion 23
```

now no need to get user permission run time in marshmallow too ..

i hope it work